# Run all the sequelize migration code through node js index file or through node command

Tags: node.js

I am very new to this `ORM` concept I know for mongoDB there is mongoose but I am working with `MYSQL` so I came to know about `sequelize` and `sequqlize-migration` but it seems very hard to me as compare to `mongoose`

My question is there any way to simplify the thing like I have my `index.js` file in and I want to run do all the action using this file so how can I do this, right now I am using this command to update the things

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

I want to run my program as

```
node index.js
```

and want the things to be done, right now there `config, migration, models` directory how to sum up the process into one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use scripts in package.json

  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate && node server.js",
  },

It will first run npx sequelize-cli thing and would wait for it to finish before running node server.js

Hope it answers your question
```

Comment: And now simple simple use npm run start to trigger the application